# How to add element-wise edges between two sets of vertices in Julia

Tags: julia, edges, connected-components, undirected-graph, lightgraphs

After running the command `connected_components` on an undirected graph `g` with LightGraphs in Julia, I obtain the following result:

```
9-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10  …  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
 [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60  …  91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
 [69, 88]
 [71, 73, 84, 102, 114, 122, 124, 127, 128, 134, 139, 143, 147, 150]
 [101, 104, 105, 111, 112, 113, 116, 117, 121, 125  …  137, 138, 140, 141, 142, 144, 145, 146, 148, 149]
 [103, 106, 108, 110, 118, 119, 123, 126, 130, 131, 132, 136]
 [107]
 [109]
 [115]
```

I want to add an element-wise edge between the vertices `107 109 115` and the vertices `91 113 102`. I know I can use the commands `add_edge!(g,107,91)` `add_edge!(g,109,113)` and `add_edge!(g,115,102)` but isn't there a command that can do all that in one shot instead of creating a loop or a function?

Thank you!

Comment: You can broadcast `add_edge!` using dot: `add_edge!.(g, [107, 109, 115], [91, 113, 102])`.

Comment: OMG! Yes! It worked! Thank you!